# How can I copy a file from a network share when I don't have read permissions on the parent folder?

Tags: windows, permissions, unc

I have a UNC path to a file which I’d like to copy of the form:

```
\\server\folder1\folder2\filename.ext
```

I have read access to this file, e.g. I can paste the path into the run dialog in Windows and the file opens in the appropriate viewer. But I do NOT have read access to the containing folder, i.e. if I run just the path portion:

```
\\server\folder1\folder2
```

I get a network access error. How can I copy the file?

Robocopy, copy, and Xcopy all fail, apparently because they try to read the folder before reading the file itself.

Comment: how about cygwin's cp? syntax like `cp /cygdrive/c/folder/file /cygdrive/c/folder/file2`  Replace c with mapped network drive as you require.  Check you can 'ls' it first.  ls is like dir.

Comment: Holy cow, that worked!  I was really not expecting that to work!  @barlop, can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct and give you all the much-deserved karma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about cygwin's cp? syntax like `cp /cygdrive/c/folder/file /cygdrive/c/folder/file2`  Replace c with mapped network drive as you require. Check you can `ls` it first. `ls` is like dir.

Comment: Remarkably, this worked like a charm!  Didn't see that one coming... thanks!